# Most efficient way to check if a stringified number is above MAX_UINT64?

Tags: string, perl, numbers

Suppose I have a script which is executed by a 64-bit Perl and which is taking one parameter which actually is a number, but of course is a string in the first place (because all command line parameters are strings).

Now, if that parameter's value fits into a 64 bit unsigned int, the script should do something with the parameter; otherwise, it should abort with an appropriate error message.

What would be the most efficient way to check if that parameter (as a string, i.e. before using it in mathematical operations) fits into a 64-bit unsigned integer?

What I already have thought of:

1. I could do a string comparison

   I don't want to do that because in that case I had to cope with collations, and the documentation for [Unicode::Collate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Collate) looks a bit oversized for my small problem.

   But this is just a feeling, so I'd be grateful for comments or other opinions.

   Side note: I have tried this, and it worked like expected. But this was just a quick test; I did not play around with locales, so on other systems it might not work (although I doubt that there is a collation which puts "2" before "1", but you never know).
2. Converting to numbers before comparing won't work:

   ```
   root@spock:/root/test# perl -e '$i="18446744073709551615"+0; $j="18446744073709551616"+0; print "$i  $j\n"; print(($i < $j) ? "less\n" : "greater or equal\n")'
   18446744073709551615  1.84467440737096e+19
   greater or equal
   ```

   Note how Perl prints the second number. This is the smallest unsigned integer which does not fit into 64 bits, so Perl converts it to a double. When it then compares `$i` and `$j` numerically, it has to convert `$i` to a double as well; due to the loss of precision involved herein, `$i` is converted to the same value as `$j`, so the comparison goes wrong.
3. I could do `use bigint;`. I have tried this, and it behaved as expected.

   But that probably would lead to a dramatic loss of performance. As far as I have understood, `use bigint;` implies the use of various heavy libraries.

   But this is just a feeling as well, so if this is the way to go, please let me know.
4. Another idea (not tried yet): Could I use `pack()` to generate a byte sequence from the stringified number somehow? Then I could check the length of that byte sequence. If it is less or equal to 8 bytes, the stringified number fits into a 64-bit unsigned integer.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Don't feel, benchmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use constant MAX_UINT64 = '18446744073709551615';

my $larger_than_max =
      length($s) > length(MAX_UINT64)
   || length($s) == length(MAX_UINT64) && $s gt MAX_UINT64;
```

Assumes input matches `/^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)\z/`. Adjust to liking (e.g. to handle leading zeros or signs).

Comment: This is nearly identical to the solution I have tried, and your assumption regarding the input is correct. So you are suggesting the string comparison method, and thus we have to think about collations. Sinan Ünür in his answer has stated that the ordering of Arabic digits is the same for *every* locale (which can be reached from Perl). I believe him, but would be interested in further opinions and references. Could you give additional pointers regarding this?

Comment: Locales don't come into play with `cmp` unless you use `use locale;` (which you shouldn't use), if at all. Normally, `cmp` performs a straight up character comparison.

Comment: Yes, this is what `perldoc perlop` and `perldoc perllocale` are saying, and this is my understanding problem: To compare characters, there must be a rule saying if a character is "higher" ("greater") than another one. So, if no locale is in effect, which are the rules used by `cmp()` to compare characters? In other words, what is a "straight character comparison"? Is it based on Unicode code points? If yes, my problem would be solved (since the code points for Arabic digits in Unicode are the same as their ASCII codes, and those are definitely ordered as expected).

Comment: @Binarus see [I lost track; what encoding is the internal format really?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#I-lost-track%3B-what-encoding-is-the-internal-format-really%3F)

Comment: @SinanÜnür The source you gave deals with the internal *encoding* of strings in Perl. Although I know that character ordering based on the encoding can be done, I can't believe (yet) that it is the default. I think that ordering characters based on Unicode code points would make more sense. But to make it clear to me: Do you say that Perl's default character ordering as used by `cmp()` is based on the *internal character encodings* (i.e. the byte sequences representing those characters in memory) instead of *Unicode code points*?

Comment: A string is just an array of numbers.  It's literally comparing those numbers. In this case, those numbers are Unicode Code Points if you properly decoded your inputs

Comment: @Binarus I answered the literal question you asked in your comment. Seriously?

Comment: @SinanÜnür Please excuse me, but (unless I have misunderstood something) I think you didn't. How characters are *internally encoded* does not have to do anything with their ordering or meaning (although you *could* do an ordering based on *encoding*). Finally, ikegami (in the previous comment) has pointed out that the comparison is done based on *Unicode code points* (and *not* based on their *encoding*), as I already suspected.

Comment: @Ikegami Thanks, answer accepted and +1 for all your comments. Finally, your statement that the ordering is based on the Unicode code points (as I already suspected) solved my problem.

Comment: It's only based on Unicode Code Points if you provide Unicode Code Points. It's actually just a simple numerical comparison

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple shortcut that should eliminate most numbers. Any number that has 19 or fewer digits in the decimal representation can fit in a 64 bit integer, so if the length of the string containing the integer is less than 20, it is good.

Any string with length greater than or equal to 21 is bad.

`UINT64_MAX` is `18446744073709551615`. So, there are some numbers with 20 decimal digits can fit a 64 bit unsigned integer. Some can't.

At this point, simple string comparison using `ge` will be enough because the ordering of Arabic digits is the same regardless of locale.

```
$ perl -E "say 'yes' if $ARGV[1] ge $ARGV[0]" 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551616
yes
```

Comment: Exponents would throw that off?  `perl -wE'$x += $_ for @ARGV; say $x' 1 2e18` prints the whole thing but it prints it rounded for `2e19`.

Comment: I don't see where exponents come in.

Comment: A string `2e19` has length four but it exceeds the precision limit.  Maybe I am misunderstanding it?

Comment: Did the OP say anything about arguments containing exponents?

Comment: Well, no no, they did not. But it's conceivable, specially with big numbers.

Comment: @zdim No, you are not misunderstanding, but I should have mentioned that the stringified number in question will *always* be in the general, natural, usual format (no scientific notation, no other chars than digits, just a sequence of digits how you would expect it).

Comment: @SinanÜnür What you are describing in your answer is exactly what I have tested. But the key point in your answer is the statement that the ordering of Arabic digits is the same in *every* locale. I believe you because of your reputation score and since this was my expectation as well, but nevertheless: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Binarus See, for example, [this draft of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "*In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.*" I believe the C++ language has the exact same sentence as well. These are all laying down as a rule what has for a long time been true. The code of `3` is  less than `4` (in fact, the code of `3` is exactly 1 less than the code of `4`) regardless of locale.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the input is a string of digits for clarity.

You ask for the most efficient way.  This can't be determined without understanding the distribution of inputs.   For example if the inputs are uniform in 128 bit integers, the most efficient is to start with something like:

```
if (length(@ARGV[0]) > 20) {die "Number too large.\n"}
```

This deals with over 99.9999999999 % of cases.  In fact if the inputs were uniform in 256 bit integers you might be forgiven for simply writing:

```
warn "Number too large.\n";
```

As to repeatedly and consistently testing in a reasonable amount of time you could consider something like this regex from Damian Conway's Regexp::Number (for signed 64 bit numbers but the principle is valid).  Notice, being real code, it deals with leading zeros.

```
 '0*(?:(?:9(?:[0-1][0-9]{17}'  .
        '|2(?:[0-1][0-9]{16}'  .
        '|2(?:[0-2][0-9]{15}'  .
        '|3(?:[0-2][0-9]{14}'  .
        '|3(?:[0-6][0-9]{13}'  .
        '|7(?:[0-1][0-9]{12}'  .
        '|20(?:[0-2][0-9]{10}' .
        '|3(?:[0-5][0-9]{9}'   .
        '|6(?:[0-7][0-9]{8}'   .
        '|8(?:[0-4][0-9]{7}'   .
        '|5(?:[0-3][0-9]{6}'   .
        '|4(?:[0-6][0-9]{5}'   .
        '|7(?:[0-6][0-9]{4}'   .
        '|7(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}'   .
        '|5(?:[0-7][0-9]{2}'   .
        '|80(?:[0-6])))))))))))))))))' .
  '|[1-8]?[0-9]{0,18})'
```

This should be blindingly fast compared with perl run-up time for example, or even a keystroke.

As to bigint, it executes very quickly and includes some cool optimization features, but unless you are testing many numbers in code the above should suffice.

If you really want to burn rubber, though, take a look at perl guts, and use something that exposes the macro SvIOK(SV*).   (See https://metacpan.org/pod/release/KRISHPL/pod2texi-0.1/perlguts.pod#What-is-an-%22IV%22? for more details.)